# How to combine some similar pattern data in one column of mysql, to get the count?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like below

[image]

From this table, I want to get the counts of SearchParams, which I tried like this:

[image]

But I want all the data which is matching the pattern "TVE-xxxx" should be combined as "TVE" and the count.

Please help.

Comment: Don't post images of code etc, because now we can't copy your query and modify it. And I'm too lazy to write it all from the beginning...

Comment: Do you have known pattern like 3 differences for TVE-? or Dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to determine the value on which you group by:

```
select 
  case when searchParam like 'TVE-%' then 'TVE' else searchParam end groupParam,
  count(*) counter
from careinsight.testtable
group by groupParam
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

To filter data with pattern **"TVE-xxx"** , use below query

```
select name,count(name) 
from tblName
where name REGEXP '^TVE\-[a-zA-Z]{3}$'
group by name
```

Comment: OP wants to group the different TVE rows together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have known differences in pattern, you can use CASE/WHEN to summarize your output as below. This case you have to know the list of value may come for one group like 'Account' and you need to put them in the list of IN for the CASE statement.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN searchParam IN ('AccountSVNC','AccountSVNC') THEN 'Account'
    WHEN searchParam IN ('TVE-ABC','TVE-CDE','TVE-MFG') THEN 'TVE'
    ELSE searchParam
END searchParam,
COUNT(searchParam)     
FROM your_table
GROUP BY  
CASE 
    WHEN searchParam IN ('AccountSVNC','AccountSVNC') THEN 'Account'
    WHEN searchParam IN ('TVE-ABC','TVE-CDE','TVE-MFG') THEN 'TVE'
    ELSE searchParam
END
```